# Performance tuning of a query processing millions of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I've got a query processing 2 tables with over 61 million records each.

- **WB_YH_BCUPDATE_FULL_BASE:** table containing customers and all the months they were active. (from 2014 till now)

> CUSTOMERNUMBER | CAR MONTH
>
> ---
>
> 99999 | 201401
>   99999 | 201402
>   99999 | 201403
>   ....

- **WB_YH_BCUPDATE_MATCH_MONTH:** table containing customers and all the months that were active with + a fictive extra field containing the CAR_MONTH + 6 months.

> CUSTOMERNUMBER    | CAR_MONTH | MATCH_MONTH_6
>
> ---
>
> 99999 | 201401 | 201407
>   99999 | 201402 | 201408
>   99999 | 201403 | 201409
>   ...

Now I want to check for all customers and all of their corresponding CAR_MONTHS if they were still active (= they appear in the table) after 6 months. For this I need to use the field I created, being MATCH_MONTH_6.

I'm using the following query:

```
select distinct a.CUSTOMERNUMBER
   , a.CAR_MONTH
   , b.MATCH_MONTH_6
   , CASE WHEN b.CUSTOMERNUMBER is null then 0
          ELSE 1
     END FL_MATCH_6         
from WB_YH_BCUPDATE_FULL_BASE a left join WB_YH_BCUPDATE_MATCH_MONTH b
                                on a.CUSTOMERNUMBER =  b.CUSTOMERNUMBER      
                                and a.CAR_MONTH = b.CAR_MONTH 
                                and b.MATCH_MONTH_6 in (
                                select CAR_MONTH
                                from   WB_YH_BCUPDATE_FULL_BASE
                                where  customernumber = a.customernumber
                                );
```

The performance of my query is really poor as you can see from the following Execution Plan:

```
 Plan Hash Value  : 3376431373 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id   | Operation                          | Name                           | Rows     | Bytes      | Cost      | Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |                                | 25897713 |  673340538 | 371846479 | 02:56:04 |
|    1 |   HASH UNIQUE                      |                                | 25897713 |  673340538 | 371846479 | 02:56:04 |
|    2 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER              |                                | 61874441 | 1608735466 | 371674345 | 02:55:59 |
|    3 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL      | WB_YH_BCUPDATE_FULL_BASE       | 61874441 |  742493292 |      3225 | 00:00:01 |
|    4 |     VIEW                           |                                |        1 |         14 |         6 | 00:00:01 |
|    5 |      NESTED LOOPS                  |                                |        1 |         31 |         6 | 00:00:01 |
|    6 |       NESTED LOOPS                 |                                |       24 |         31 |         6 | 00:00:01 |
|  * 7 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | WB_YH_BCUPDATE_MATCH_MONTH     |        1 |         19 |         3 | 00:00:01 |
|  * 8 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN           | WB_YH_BCUPDATE_MATCH_MONTH_IND |       24 |            |         2 | 00:00:01 |
|  * 9 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN            | WB_YH_BCUPDATE_FULL_BASE_IND   |       24 |            |         2 | 00:00:01 |
| * 10 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | WB_YH_BCUPDATE_FULL_BASE       |        1 |         12 |         3 | 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 7 - filter("A"."CAR_MONTH"="B"."CAR_MONTH")
* 8 - access("A"."CUSTOMERNUMBER"="B"."CUSTOMERNUMBER")
* 9 - access("CUSTOMERNUMBER"="A"."CUSTOMERNUMBER")
* 10 - filter("CAR_MONTH"=TO_NUMBER("B"."MATCH_MONTH_6"))
```

Do you guys have any idea on how I can optimize this query or how I can rewrite this query to be more performant?

Kind regards,

Comment: You need indexes on the tables.  The `join` conditions are a good place to start.

Comment: So `WB_YH_BCUPDATE_MATCH_MONTH` contains the same data as `WB_YH_BCUPDATE_FULL_BASE`, but with one extra column?

Comment: I've got indexes on both tables on the field CUSTOMERNUMBER. And @SQB; That's correct, but I didn't manage to get the results in another way without duplicating the data in 2 tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
   a.customernumber,
   a.car_month,
   b.car_month AS match_month_6,
   CASE
      WHEN b.customernumber IS NULL
      THEN 0
      END 1
   END AS fl_match_6
FROM WB_YH_BCUPDATE_MATCH_MONTH a
LEFT JOIN WB_YH_BCUPDATE_MATCH_MONTH b
   ON (a.customernumber = b.Customernumber AND a.match_month_6 = b.car_month);
```

Since you say that `WB_YH_BCUPDATE_MATCH_MONTH` contains the same data as `WB_YH_BCUPDATE_FULL_BASE`, but with one extra column, we can use the former and ignore the latter.

We now left join it with itself. Of course on the customer number, but also, we join the date + 6 months on the date. If the customer was active 6 months later, we will find an entry; if not, we won't.

To completely duplicate the results of your query, we select get our data for match_month_6 from the left joined table, since it was NULL if we couldn't get a match in your original query as well.

You should put indexes on both month fields as well, since we join on those too.

---

Note that this doesn't guarantee that the customer was active in the months in between. I a customer was active in January and in July, they will be returned by this query.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Query seems to do exactly what I want to achieve with a great performance. I'm aware of the fact that this doesn't quarantee that the customer was active in the months in between. Creating a field for this is the next step I want to achieve. :)

Comment: @wbaeckelmans just out of curiosity, what was the gain in performance?

Answer (score 0):

```
select w1.CUSTOMERNUMBER, w1.CAR_MONTH, nvl2(w2.CUSTOMERNUMBER, 'Yes', 'No') active_in_6_months
  from WB_YH_BCUPDATE_FULL_BASE w1 
  left outer join WB_YH_BCUPDATE_MATCH_MONTH w2 
  on (w1.CUSTOMERNUMBER = w2. CUSTOMERNUMBER and w1.CAR_MONTH = w2.MATCH_MONTH_6);
```

This query should give you desired result with better performance.

Comment: I've tried this query and the performance is great but it didn't gave me the desired result. I've looked up some specific customers that stated no as active after 6 months but they seem to have been active during the full period.

Comment: This returns the customers that were active 6 months before. Same idea, but from another point of view.

Comment: @SQB you're right I should join a little bi different. I see you already posted amended query.